# Ternary opertor output

Tags: c

I have come across a piece of code. I am wondering why is the below code returning the value of x as four and not zero.

```
 if(2<1);
 else x = (2<0) ? printf("one") : printf("four");
 printf("%d",x);
```

**output is 4**

Comment: Why do you think it should set it to `0`? `printf()` returns the number of characters printed, so it should be either `3` or `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `printf` returns the number of printed characters.

Because in this conditional operator

```
 (2<0)?printf("one"):printf("four")
```

the condition `(2<0)` is false this expression `printf("four")` is evaluated and its value is equal to 4 - the number of the outputed characters.

From the description of function `printf` (the C Standard, 7.21.6.3 The printf function)

> 3 The printf function **returns the number of characters
>   transmitted**, or a negative value if an output or encoding error
>   occurred.

I think that the reason of the confusion is the assignment operator before the 
conditional operator. However the assignment operator has lower priority compared with the conditional operator. So in fact you have

```
 else x = ( (2<0) ? printf("one") : printf("four") );
```

Comment: but I think x = 2<0 has x =false value i.e x=0, then it goes to printf and assigns value 4.. This is some tricky one

Comment: @niks The condition in the ternary operator is logical Or expression that also has higher priority than the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

Please instead of trying to read the unreadable, make it readable and enjoy

```
if (2 < 1);
else 
    x = (2 < 0) ? printf("one") : printf("four");
printf("%d", x);
```

Of course `2 < 1` is false, and `2 < 0` is false again so the return value of `printf("four")` which is `4` because `"four"` has 4 characters is assigned to `"x"`.

So the output should be

```
four4
```

Comment: why there's a `;` after `if`? won't it complain about missing `if` for `else`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It was in the original code, it doesn't matter since it's an "*empty*" statement.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Also doesn't matter because it continues straight to `else`

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's an empty statement. That means if the condition is true, don't do anything.

Comment: Yes and the recommended way is to use an empty block instead of the `;`. because that way it's more clear, `{}`. Of course, in real life it doesn't make sense because one can simple write `if (1 <= 2)` and remove the `else`.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of two statements without a block.